# How to make a global variable in tkinter?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, global

I have declared a variable inside a function and now want to use it
password_input_box1.place(x=200, y=180)  # password enter box
password_input_box1.get()

Comment: Can you post the entire code for your function? You could just return `username_input_box1` and `password_input_box1` from your function.

Comment: This isn’t up to tkinter. You just use normal python techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global` keyword to tell Python it's a global variable.

```
username_input_box1 = None
password_input_box1 = None

def myfun():
   global username_input_box1, password_input_box1
   username_input_box1 = Entry(root19, width=30)
   username_input_box1.place(x=200, y=153)  # name enter box
   username_input_box1.get()

   password_input_box1 = Entry(root19, width=30)
   password_input_box1.place(x=200, y=180)  # password enter box
   password_input_box1.get()
```